# bifunctor in haskell after the least fixed type

Tags: haskell, functor, recursive-datastructures, free-monad

I am not sure how to derive the functor instance after making a fixed point :

```
data FreeF f a next  = PureF a | FreeF (f next)  deriving (Functor)

data Mu f  = In { out :: f ( Mu f ) }

newtype Free f a = Free(  Mu (FreeF f a)  )

instance Functor f => Functor (Free f) where
     fmap h (Free (out -> PureF a))  = Free (In (PureF (h a)))
     fmap h (Free (out -> FreeF fn)) = Free (In (fmap undefined undefined)) --stuck
```

If I modify Mu to accept an extra type parameter, I can progress until... :

```
data Mu f a  = In { out :: f ( Mu f a )  } deriving (Functor)

newtype Free f a = Free(  Mu (FreeF f a) a )

instance Functor f => Functor (Free f ) where
     fmap h (Free (out -> PureF a))  = Free . In . PureF $ h a
     fmap h (Free (out -> FreeF fn)) = Free . In . FreeF $ fmap undefined fn
```

Here I need to have `undefined :: Mu (FreeF f a) a -> Mu (FreeF f b) b` but `mu f` is a functor for the same `f` and here it varies in type.

What is the correct way to tackle this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `mu f` is a functor for the same `f` and here it varies in type.

Fortunately we're defining `Functor (Free f)`, and we actually use this `Functor` instance to map over the `a`'s in the `PureF` constructors. `Functor (Free f)` abstracts over all "internal" occurrences of `a`.

So, whenever we want to map over both occurrences of `a`, for example when we want to implement `FreeF f a (Mu (FreeF f a)) -> FreeF f b (Mu (FreeF f b))`, we can do that by wrapping everything up all the way back to `Free`, mapping, then unwrapping again.

The following checks out with your original data definitions:

```
newtype Free f a = Free {unFree :: Mu (FreeF f a)} -- add "unFree"

instance Functor f => Functor (Free f) where
     fmap h (Free (In (PureF a)))  = Free (In (PureF (h a)))
     fmap h (Free (In (FreeF fn))) =
       Free (In (FreeF (fmap (unFree . fmap h . Free) fn)))
```

Some testing:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances, StandaloneDeriving #-}

deriving instance Show (f (Mu f)) => Show (Mu f)
deriving instance Show (Mu (FreeF f a)) => Show (Free f a)       

foo :: Free [] Int
foo = Free $ In $ FreeF [ In $ PureF 100, In $ PureF 200 ]

> fmap (+100) foo
Free {unFree = In {out = FreeF [In {out = PureF 200},In {out = PureF 300}]}}
```

Comment: Isn't `In . out` redundant? (both occurrences)

Comment: It is. I guess I followed the type holes a bit too dumbly. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done this construction before, but I think I'm seeing something. Your intuition about adding an argument to `Mu` is good, but you need to pass it along so that `Free f` fits, i.e. so that `f` takes two arguments instead of one:

```
newtype Mu f a = In { out :: f (Mu f a) a }
```

`Mu f` ought to be a `Functor` under suitable conditions, which would give you the instance you're looking for.  What are those conditions?  We need:

```
fmap' :: (a -> b) -> f (Mu f a) a -> f (Mu f b) b
```

We expect `f` to be functorial in its second argument, so that's no problem.  So what we really need a way to get

```
f (Mu f a) b -> f (Mu f b) b
           ^               ^
           +--not varying--+
```

We can use the instance recursively to get `Mu f a -> Mu f b`, so it looks like we just need `f` to be a functor in its first argument too.  Hence:

```
class Bifunctor f where
    bimap :: (a -> c) -> (b -> d) -> f a b -> f c d
```

Then you should be able to write the suitable instances

```
instance (Functor f) => Bifunctor (FreeF f) ...
instance (Bifunctor f) => Functor (Mu f) ...
```

Comment: indeed that's what i was thinking of doing. interesting !